# How to detect google map v2 loading complete in android

Tags: android, google-maps-android-api-2

I'm have a fragment to load map use google map API v2 in android.
I want to detect when map loading complete to show a user guideline how to use app.
Have any idea to solve this problem?
Thank you!

Comment: http://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=5779

Comment: ok, thank you. I have stared it.